# Equal sign in a for loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

Please explain what is happening in the loop below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
x = 0
for i in a:
    x += i == 1
    print x
```

What does `==` do above?

Comment: You'd probably have avoided the downvotes had you explained why the `==` is surprising. I suspect it is the summing of booleans that has you puzzled here.

Comment: Well what does `==` usually do? Have you e.g. tested this in the interpreter? What exactly is it you find difficult to understand within the code?

Answer (score 3):

`==` is the [equality operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#equals). It returns a boolean, `True` if `i` is equal to 1, `False` otherwise.

Python booleans are a subclass of `int`, and summing them is a valid option; `True` is equal to 1, `False` equal to `0`.

`x += (expression)` uses an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements); the result of the expression is added to `x`.

So each time `i` is equal to `1`, `x` is incremented by 1:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> i == 1
True
>>> 0 + (i == 1)
1
>>> 5 + (i == 1)
6
```

The code then counts how many elements in `a` are equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question instead of downvoting, you are the best. A real constructive python guru.

Answer (score 3):

This looks kind of like a homework problem, but I'll nibble (not quite a bite).

What would you say it does if I added grouping like this:

```
x += (i == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` in python as in `C/C++` is for equality, a relational operator.

`x += i == 1` is equated as `x += (i == 1)`, which means

`Add 1 to x iff i is equal to 1`

The COde can be equivalently written as

```
for i in a:
    if i == 1:
        x += 1
    else:
        x += 0
    print x
```

Comment: Great answer, the last line in your answer explains everything.

Comment: But the code in my question prints `2` 3 times. Shouldn't it print `1` 3 times?

Comment: No, it print thrice because the print statement is executed thrice. I am extending my answer to enhance the understanding

Comment: @alwbtc: your code would only print `2` 3 times if you re-ran your loop. Make sure you reset `x` before you run the loop again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are a python wizard. I am a keen admirer of your python knowledge